# How to clear a table before inserting rows in it?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

Before you keep reading, keep in mind I have done my research and I still cant find a solution. So I've got a table that I am populating with JQuery and it populates it properly but I can't seem to be able to clear it before populating it again. Here is my HTML:

```js
$("#searchBut").click(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').remove();

  var searchT = $('#searchField').val();
  var results = $('#logs');
  results.innerHTML = 'test';
  console.log("results" + results);
  $.post('includes/searchProj.php', {
    projName: searchT
  }, function(data) {
    var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data2, function(key, val) {
      pArray.push("<tr><td> " + val.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.note + "</td>" + "<td>" + "</td>" + " </tr>");
    });

    $("<tbody>", {
      "class": "tbody",
      html: pArray.join("")
    }).appendTo("table");
    /*$('.tbody').append(pArray.join(''));*/
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" style="width:50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Project Name</th>
      <th>Date Created</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th>Total Time for Project</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have also tried `$('tbody > tr').clear()` and `$('tbody > tr').html("");` and played around with selecting it with tbody or table and a couple other variations.

Nothing seems to clear the table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `.appendTo`?

Comment: document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = ''";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### logic

Since what you are wanting to do is remove DOM elements with the tag `tbody` that are children of the `table` element with id `table`, you can:

1. find each element
2. remove the element from the parent

#### implementation

1. find each element:

   - `var body_elements = document.querySelectorAll('#table tbody')`

     - see CSS query selectors for syntax of what parameters to pass to the `querySelectorAll` method
2. remove each element from parent (removing each element from the page)

   - `body_elements.forEach((element)=>{ element.parentNode.removeChild(element)});`

#### all together

```
var body_elements = document.querySelectorAll('#table .tbody')
body_elements.forEach((element)=>{
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element) 
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it still appends to the table and does not clear it

Comment: @ShLuBsTeR When you run this code alone, does it clear the table?

Comment: I cant tell because the table is empty by default, its for a search page  and when you go to the page the table is empty, then when you search for a project, it gets the project details and puts it in the table but then it keeps  appending it to the table instead of clearing it the next time i search. Thi is for work so i dont want to change the layout of the page too much, i just need to figure out how to clear it

Comment: @ShLuBsTeR Populate the table with one set of search results and then run that code (either manually through the developer console or just make a function with that code that gets triggered with a button). We need to see if this code does not work or if there is a different problem.

Comment: Okay so i hardcoded in a table row and now it works to get rid of that row but when i try to run it with the append it still appends to the table and does not clear the other information

Comment: @ShLuBsTeR I think your `pArray` variable is a global variable. In other words, your code constantly adds elements to that array and never clears them. add `var pArray = []` at the beginning of the `.click({ ...` function.

Comment: Yes i just realized that and put it in the click function andnow it works! thank you very much!